# Where are the date entries in the database - WooCommerce events manager by CybersourcePK

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm unable to find where the event's dates are published on the WordPress database side. (`event_date`, `event_end_date`).
The only record for the product is located in the posts table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned plugin stores the data in wp_postmeta table with `post_id` set to product ID and respective value against the meta_key `event_datetime`, `event_end_date`, `expire_product`.

You can get the more inside by looking into the function `process_product_meta_event_tab()` present in `/wp-content/plugins/woo-event-manager/woocommerce-events-manager.php`.

Hope this helps!